# Logged in indicator, but not entirely logged in

Tags: bug, login, top-bar

I have landed on the question page, and it looked like I was logged in.  There was a logged-in indicator, there were some new issues (new comments) and some new reputation since I was last there.  I was able to see issues, but when I wanted to see the source of new reputation, it turned out that I was not logged in...

See the screenshot below

[image: Logged in for top bar, but not logged in for new reputation]

After logging in using the link, everything worked correctly.

Comment: you can add a freehand circle around the **389** rep point in the right